# php mysql вложенные списки с разных таблиц

Tags: php, mysql

заинтересовался реализацией вложенных структур. как известно в mysql нельзя делать поля с результатом из других таблиц (поле массив)
допустим имеется 3 произвольных таблицы, допустим страна область и город
таблицы связаны по id

страна имеет столбцы id и country_name

область имеет столбцы id country_id district_name

город имеет столбцы  id district_id city_name

количество вложений известно.

как правильно будет сделать...

**1** приджоинить таблицы друг к другу и в php перебрать все результаты приведя к нужному массиву со вложениями?

```
["country"=>"russia",
 "districts"=>[
              "district"=>"Moskowskaya obl",
                "cityes"=>["Moskva",]  
              ]
]//(ну это примерно)
```

или

**2** сделать первоначальную выборку по странам, потом во вложенных циклах делать выборки областей и городов?

**3** может есть более правильный более правильный вариант?

Comment: *как известно в mysql нельзя делать поля с результатом из других таблиц (поле массив)* Это неверно. Есть JSON-массивы, есть иные представления массивов (да хоть бы и CSV).

Comment: *может есть более правильный более правильный вариант?* Результат содержит 2 уровня агрегации. Соответственно внутренняя выполняется в CTE или подзапросе, а внешняя во внешнем запросе.